# How to implement Jquery in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to implement this block of code Jquery in React JS:

```
(function(){

   $("#cart").on("click", function() {
     $(".shopping-cart").fadeToggle( "fast");
   });

 })();
```

It's possible?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: That code does a number of different things (pointless closure, selecting elements, listen for click events, something that looks like it probably animates something): Which one are you having problems with?

Comment: Don't. Just don't. I have lost count of how many people try to integrate jQuery with React or Angular. These libraries are radically different and absolutely not meant to be mixed together. Do things the React's or Angular's way and do NOT mix up these frameworks.

Comment: @JeremyThille i need to implement React JS only?

Comment: That's exactly what I've said, yes :)

Comment: Any example to guide me for doing that? thanks @JeremyThille

Comment: Yes, do not load jQuery and forget about it. Job done.

Comment: @JeremyThille i said functional example xD

Comment: Well, there are _plenty_ of React tutorials on the Internet. Use Google...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery and React are very different beasts, with completely different workflows.  For your jQuery example, you only need to include the right markup on the page, and jQuery will manipulate it for you.

React creates its own markup, which you don't directly modify at all.

The simplest way to do what you're trying to achieve would most likely be a CSS transition which you enact by setting a `className` on your react component when it is clicked.

For more information, take a look at this [excellent article](https://medium.com/@joethedave/achieving-ui-animations-with-react-the-right-way-562fa8a91935) on the subject by Joe Davis.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible but React and its generated HTML is not meant to be manipulated as jquery does.
If you want a fade out animation in React it is better to rely on CSS animations and transitions, adding and removing CSS classes.

Check out the "*Integrating with other libraries*" section of the official docs:
https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Answer (score -2):

To execute jquery in react you need to include the jquery js "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" in your page.Then it work like a charm.
Though you shouldn't be doing it in react philosophy.

```
componentWillMount () {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = "https://use.typekit.net/foobar.js";
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
```

Comment: Given the way React dynamicaly generates elements: simply adding that line is very unlikely to be sufficient.

Comment: Being able to load jQuery in a React app does not mean you should. And it turns out, you really SHOULDN'T.